# Simulate a JavaScript Button click with a Linux/Windows CLI line tool (http request)

Tags: javascript, http, curl, request

Got a classic JS button :

```
<button class="my-button" OnClick="(windows.open('https://anotherwebsite.com'))">CLICK ME</button>
```

I would like to trigger this button with a CLI tool like cURL for example.Is that possible ?

I did my research before asking, i found a lot of questions about the opposite (how to curl into a javascript) but not mine.

I already know that u can use selenium w/ python/java... or any other alternatives like Jaunt w/ java but it has to come almost out of the box, i don't want to be stuck with some dependencies and i want it light. I have heard about XHR request but i'm kinda confuse since i saw how to run them with a specific language through methods/functions but not with a cli line tool.

PS : I'm not interested in :

```
curl https://anotherwebsite.com
```

It HAS to trigger the javascript just like if i go straight to my chrome dev tool>Console and type windows.open('blabla').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the desired behavior using [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and cURL. But prepare, it will take a lot of steps :)

You need to perform the following actions:

- Download the driver from the aforementioned link and unarchive it to any folder
- Start the driver (`./chromedriver &` on Unix or `chromedriver.exe` on Windows). You'll see the message, find the port. In my case the message was%

> Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port **9515**

- Connect to the driver session via cURL `curl  -d '{ "desiredCapabilities": { "caps": { "nativeEvents": false, "browserName": "chrome", "version": "", "platform": "ANY" } } }'  http://localhost:9515/session`. In the output of this command, find the **sessionId**, in my case it was **e2fafa7a017a6be7136a02af694f5493**
- Open the page with the button `curl -d '{"url":"<your url>"}' http://localhost:9515/session/e2fafa7a017a6be7136a02af694f5493/url`
- Find the button (I use `name` as a locator, but I believe `class` will work as well) `curl -d '{"using":"name","value":"<your-value>"}' http://localhost:9515/session/27f4262ab044392b05138540055a8fd6/element`. In the output of this command you have to find the `ELEMENT` value. In my case it was **0.044231492091793445-1**
- Finally, click it! `curl -X POST  http://localhost:9515/session/e2fafa7a017a6be7136a02af694f5493/element/0.044231492091793445-1/click`
- You did it, now close the session `curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9515/session/e2fafa7a017a6be7136a02af694f5493`

As you see, you have to perform a lot of actions, but I believe it matches your requirements. For more information please refer to [this](https://www.pawangaria.com/post/automation/browser-automation-from-command-line/) and [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) links. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot this is a really good answer, unfortunately after 1 hour of try hard i did find my button with element but the way to find it is wrong so it does not work all the time.

It make the solution not viable. 

I simplified for the purpose of the answer but i have a full table of 12 buttons i need to activate, theses buttons are validated with a token, so when i trigger one, page reload and ELEMENT id changes and i can't find 2nd button ELEMENT id easily.

Thanks tho, i will find another way to do this

Comment: I'd try to use https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
Sorry I didn't manage to fully cover your needs :(
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use [jQuery ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp), but if you want vanilla js then you do need to create an XHR request via `XMLHttpRequest`.  The following will create a GET request. Something you need to keep in mind is CORS. It is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). Unfortunately, unlike curl browsers do have that extra layer of security because they are much more popular then terminals.

[Source for the below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

```
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.phtml?figure1=5&figure2=10", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
 alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
```

Comment: How can i throw this into a bash script ? What language is this ?